# Eruv Tavshilin for Shabbat on first day of Yom Tov

Tags: shabbat, yom-tov, eruv-tavshilin

Today I received a voicemail from the Chicago Center for Torah and Chesed reminding me to make an eruv tavshilin for this coming yom tov. The only problem is that this coming yom tov starts on Friday night. I was not aware that anybody makes an eruv for such a yom tov (nor can I think of a reason for doing so). So am I missing something or was the automated message sent in error?

Comment: maybe they meant second yom tov and just sent it too far in advance?

Comment: Maybe it meant Eruv Chatzerot, which are often reset on Erev Pesach?

Comment: To clarify... It was later confirmed that the voicemail was sent in error.

Answer (score 2):

Eruv Tavshilin is required only when Yom Tov itself is on Friday. not Erev Yom Tov. This year, and next, it occurs on just one day during the Jewish year - the Thursday eve. prior to the beginning of the 7th day of Pesach.

If the message referred to this Friday, it is an error.